# How to create a group with multiple interrelated columns along with sorting on date columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've data like below

```
CLAIM_NO RELATED DATE_REPORTED  OCCURRED_DATE   CLOSURE_DATE
151987   10890   21/02/2008 3/02/2008   25/06/2008
151987   10678   21/02/2008 3/02/2008   25/06/2008
131985   10678   21/02/2008 3/02/2008   25/06/2008
551990   10678   6/02/2008  3/02/2008   21/02/2008
271991   10890   7/03/2008  2/02/2008   10/03/2008
```

We need to identify from above data
if single claim is present in multiple related or not. If yes then that related does have any other claims or not.

There would be more claims like this which is tagged to multiple related and that related having one or more claim.

To get the Primary claim need to sort on columns in sequence like DATE_REPORTED, OCCURRED_DATE, CLOSURE_DATE. If there is tie on CLOSURE_DATE so which claim has minimum value will be considered as primary and other's are secondary.

My requirement is to generate the data like below

```
Primary_Claim   Secondary Claim
131985          551990
131985          271991
131985          151987
```

I've tried to do give rank using Row_number and Dense_rank to get the output like below

```
row_number() over (partition by Claim_no order by date_reported, occurred_date, closure_date, claim_number)
```

```
CLAIM_NO RELATED DATE_REPORTED  OCCURRED_DATE   CLOSURE_DATE    RN
131985   10678   21/02/2008 3/02/2008   25/06/2008  1
151987   10678   21/02/2008 3/02/2008   25/06/2008  2
551990   10678   6/02/2008  3/02/2008   21/02/2008  3
271991   10890   7/03/2008  2/02/2008   10/03/2008  4
```

After that I'm writing case statement like below to identify primary and secondary

```
Case when rn = 1 then claim_no end as prm_claim
Case when rn <> 1 then claim_no end as sec_claim
```

```
Primary_Claim   Secondary Claim
NULL            551990
NULL            271991
NULL            151987
131985          NULL
```

I need the primary data to be repeated for all secondary data, so doing self join with same data set which is working for few claims but when taking all the claims from the table it's not working.

TIA

Comment: Try giving input data and expected result in better format

Answer (score 0):

So using a CTE for the fake table to make this simpler to test:

```
with fake_table(CLAIM_NO, RELATED, DATE_REPORTED, OCCURRED_DATE, CLOSURE_DATE) as (
    select 
        column1, 
        column2, 
        to_date(column3, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
        to_date(column4, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
        to_date(column5, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
    from values 
        (151987, 10890, '21/02/2008', '3/02/2008', '25/06/2008'),
        (151987, 10678, '21/02/2008', '3/02/2008', '25/06/2008'),
        (131985, 10678, '21/02/2008', '3/02/2008', '25/06/2008'),
        (551990, 10678, '6/02/2008', '3/02/2008', '21/02/2008'),
        (271991, 10890, '7/03/2008', '2/02/2008', '10/03/2008')
)
```

thus you ROW_NUMBER when changed to use the RELATED not the CLAIM_NO as you have noted

```
select *
    ,row_number() over (partition by RELATED order by date_reported, occurred_date, closure_date, CLAIM_NO) as rn
from fake_table
```

gives an output like your shown:

[image]

So we can add your primary and secondary columns:

```
select *
    ,row_number() over (partition by RELATED order by date_reported, occurred_date, closure_date, CLAIM_NO) as rn
    ,Case when rn = 1 then claim_no end as prm_claim
    ,Case when rn <> 1 then claim_no end as sec_claim
from fake_table
order by date_reported, occurred_date, closure_date, CLAIM_NO
```

which looks like your results (if we ignore your row number also is ASCENDING order, while your `rn` appears to be DESCENDING:

[image]

But really what you are wanting to know is how you smosh, the primary across all rows cheaply.

And for this, the window version of MAX is about the simplest way, as it will ignore the nulls:

```
select * exclude prm_claim
    ,MAX(prm_claim) over (partition by RELATED) as prm_claim
from (
    select *
        ,row_number() over (partition by RELATED order by date_reported, occurred_date, closure_date, CLAIM_NO) as rn
        ,Case when rn = 1 then claim_no end as prm_claim
        ,Case when rn <> 1 then claim_no end as sec_claim
    from fake_table
)
order by date_reported, occurred_date, closure_date, CLAIM_NO
```

gives:

[image]

so if you want to drop those null secondary rows QUALIFY will need to be used so the filtering is after the window MAX runs:

```
select * exclude prm_claim
    ,MAX(prm_claim) over (partition by RELATED) as prm_claim
from (
    select *
        ,row_number() over (partition by RELATED order by date_reported, occurred_date, closure_date, CLAIM_NO) as rn
        ,Case when rn = 1 then claim_no end as prm_claim
        ,Case when rn <> 1 then claim_no end as sec_claim
    from fake_table
)
QUALIFY sec_claim is not null
order by date_reported, occurred_date, closure_date, CLAIM_NO
```

I was trying to correct you row_number, but most your example data is actually inconsistent with your stated goals, and the code shown.